# GFCI Breaker in Main Panel

Tags: electrical-panel

5 Outlets in bedroom on the same breaker. None of them are GFI outlets. Outlet 1 works, Outlet 2 is a switch controlled outlet. Switch works the bottom half of outlet and it works, top half is power and it doesn't work. Other 3 outlets are dead. Any suggestions?

Comment: Check the connections in outlets 1 and two.  Look for backstabs being used. turn off breaker before doing any checking.

Comment: Can you post photos of the inside of the box for outlet number 2 please?

Comment: Does sound like a loose connection, my first choice would be a loose connection in the switch. Hot makes it to switch but not to outlet. It seems like a loose connection in a receptacle would not feed the switch.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need more info before we can help you. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Answer (score 1):

I would be looking at the switched outlet. 
If your 1,2,switch are from the closest to your panel I would go to the switched outlet first as it is quite common for a failed backstab to have this problem at the last working outlet or first non working. 
you know the switch is getting power and if backstabs are used switches are normally fed by a pigtail. 
When the switched outlets other side is fed by a back stab that would be the most likely place, if not there the switch box would be my next check.

If you pull the outlet out and everything starts working the wires need to be moved from the backstabs to the screws. If the outlet has been damaged (melted from arcing) replace it.